# Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: laravel-5.4

### Framework : Laravel 5.4

### Problem :

I got the error as title when I uploaded a file.
But if I don't upload a file, the validation is ok.
I also checked the $request, but I still don't know what is the problem.

Here is my $request schreenshot
[$request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRZgF.png)

Here is my code

```
$rules = [
          'edu_title'  => 'max:255',
          'edu_author' => 'max:10',
          'categories' => 'max:100',
          'file_name'  => 'nullable|file',
          'updated_at' => 'date|before:tomorrow'
         ];

    $messages = [
                'required' => '此欄位必填',
                'max'      => '此欄位最大長度必須小於 :max',
                'date'     => '請選擇日期',
                'before'   => '選擇的日期錯誤'
                ];

    $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if($validate->fails()) {
        return back()->witherrors($validate)->withInput();
    }

    $path = '';

    if($request->hasFile('file_name')) {
        
    $validate = Validator::make($request->file_name, ['file_name' => 'file']);
        
    if( Storage::disk('local')->exists($directories.'/'.$file_name) ) {
            return back()->with('file exists', '檔案已經存在或檔名重複')->withInput();
        }

        $path = $request->file('file_name')->storeAs(
                $directories, $file_name);             
    }
    
    OtherTeachingMaterial::find($id)->update([
                            'edu_title'  => $request->edu_title,
                            'edu_author' => $request->edu_author,
                            'file_path'  => $path,
                            'categories' => $request->categories,
                            'updated_at' => $request->updated_at
                        ]);

    return redirect()->route('others_teahcing_material.dashboard')->with('success', '更新成功');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **add** your file `rule` into your `$rules` array and **delete** your second `Validate::make()` method so your `$rules` array will be:

```
$rules = [
          'edu_title'  => 'max:255',
          'edu_author' => 'max:10',
          'categories' => 'max:100',
          'file_name'  => 'nullable|file',
          'updated_at' => 'date|before:tomorrow',
          'file_name' => 'file'
         ];
```

Comment: It works for me, thank you. But I wanna know why add the second file rule and what is that stand for? Thanks again.

Comment: That's because as soon as you don't have the `required rule` added to your `input rules` the input will not be required the second problem is the your `Validate::make()` expects an array of inputs you gave it the value of the input `$request->file_name`

Comment: So that's mean the second file rule will be used when I upload a file, is it?

Comment: If you don't upload any files no rules will be applied otherwise the `file` rule will be applied. i hope that make sense